# How to get a list of updated metadata objects using Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, query

i.e. I want to get a list of all `CustomObject`s, `ApexClass`es etc. which were updated since a given point in time. The only thing I have so far is:

```
for (String type : types) {
    ListMetadataQuery q1 = new ListMetadataQuery();
    q1.setType(type);
    ListMetadataQuery[] queries = new ListMetadataQuery[]{q1};
    FileProperties[] fps = metadataConnection.listMetadata(queries, 31.0);
    for (FileProperties fp : fps) {
        if (fp.getLastModifiedDate() > pointInTimeX) {
            doSomething(fp);
        }
    }
}
```

Needless to say, but I'd rather have it filtered on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filtration available in the metadata api queries.

You will have to do the following:

1. Fire a listMetadata Request, with

`Type = 'ApexClass'  and Folder = ''`

`Type = 'CustomObject' and Folder = ''`

2. Process the response to filter the results, The Response Looks something like

   > ```
   >  {
   >         "createdById": "00520000003eLmNAAU",
   >         "createdByName": "Gunish Rai Chawla",
   >         "createdDate": "2014-04-28T17:41:05.000Z",
   >         "fileName": "objects/CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c.object",
   >         "fullName": "CHANNEL_ORDERS__Service_Order__c",
   >         "id": "01I20000000icvUEAQ",
   >         "lastModifiedById": "00520000003eLmNAAU",
   >         "lastModifiedByName": "Gunish Rai Chawla",
   >         "lastModifiedDate": "2014-04-28T17:41:05.000Z",
   >         "manageableState": "installed",
   >         "namespacePrefix": "CHANNEL_ORDERS",
   >         "type": "CustomObject"
   >       },
   > ```

Then filter by lastModifiedDate.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, and I didn't find any other way of doing it, so I'll accept the answer.

Comment: If you do find any other solution in the future, please do share it with the group. Thanks for accepting the answer :-)